# Уникальный текст для каждого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно выводить для каждого пользователя уникальный текст, у пользователей есть уникальный ID в MySQL базе - можно как то реализовать? Брать уникальный текст желательно из .txt или MySQL бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запихните в базу для каждого ID его уникальный текст и выводите в зависимости от ID.

Comment: То есть, при регистрации каждому пользователю дается свой уникальный текст Вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @DaniilP - каким образом здесь уже появилась регистрация?

Comment: @ua6xh - ок, напишу подробнее. У меня есть регистрация на сайте, когда пользователь регистрируется то ему генерируется уникальный ID, этот ID можно вызывать переменной - мне надо каждому пользователю выдавать уникальный текст. Уникальный текст нужно брать не из пустого текста а из например .txt файла - но нельзя что бы например, двум пользователям одновременно попалось одинаковое значение.

Comment: @DaniilP можно и при регистрации прописывать, только из общего списка "текстов" нужно будет после этот уникальный текст удалить. То есть завести еще одно поле в таблице юзеров, где он будет храниться.

Comment: @Zamony - подскажите пожалуйста, как тогда из .txt файла через php удалить определенную строчку?

Comment: Считываете строки из файла в массив. Потом выбираете уникальный текст - элемент этого массива. Удаляете элемент массива. Записываете оставшиеся в файл.